# How to apply styling to all group in less

Tags: css, less

i have a styling like this:

```
.one{
   background-color: black;
}
.two{
   background-color: black;
}
.three{
   background-color: black;
}
```

can i somehow make it to be like:

```
{
    background-color:black;
    .one {

    }
    .two {

    }
    .three{

    }
}
```

In LESS ?

i dont want to use a class then put them one by one on the class one two and three

Comment: What's wrong with using .one, .two, .three { background-color: black } ?

Comment: then every time i add more, i will have to add to 2 part, one is for the shared one as stated, and the other one is for custom one, imagine if i have hundreds later, how messy my code will be

Comment: You can have each of those classes on a different line if that helps, but otherwise I don't see how what you've suggested is any cleaner?

Comment: Thinking about this further the flaw with what you have suggested is that imagine having hundreds of styles all called styleXXX where XXX is the number of that selector (for the sake of explanation) and you wanted to apply a black background to the first hundred. What you suggested fits nicely, but what if you now want to apply red text to say style50 - style150. Then you wanted to apply a top margin to say style75 through to style110. That would get super messy and would make the stylesheet totally unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

```
.one, .two, .three {
       background-color: black;
}
```

This is the easiest way to use by including all classes together and applying the property.And if you still want to change the property of two say then

```
.two{
   background-color:grey;
}
```

This will override the upper one so two will be grey now.
Hope it helped!!

Comment: hmmm i wish it can be simpler, because if i have a lot of class it will be messy on the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.one, .two, .three {
background-color: black;
}
```